# U-Boot not load on the screen

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, raspberry-pi2, u-boot

I followed this steps:
git clone git://git.denx.de/u-boot.git

cd u-boot

make rpi_2_defconfig

make all

after that,
This will give a u-boot.bin binary that will work on the Raspberry Pi2, transfer this to  Raspberry Pi and change the kernel in config.txt to read:
kernel=u-boot.bin

U-Boot not load on the screen,i checked with HDMI,Serial...

Comment: apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabi-

config.txt include  kernel=uboot.bin

if you have theoretical knowledge about this things so don't reply ,and if you really work on it so reply all steps for its..

i refered this sites for understanding:
1)http://elinux.org/RPi_U-Boot
2)https://blog.night-shade.org.uk/2015/05/booting-a-raspberry-pi2-with-u-boot-and-hyp-enabled/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i solved it.

i included this below described files and config.txt include kernel=u-boot.bin, 
u-boot.bin generated from u-boot bootloader and remaining file are  downloaded from git or another resource for specific board which are used for bootloader at boot time

1)start.elf

2)bootcode.bin

3)u-boot.bin

4)config.txt

Comment: I am having similar problem as you could you please tell me if the config.txt is specific to the used board Raspberry Pi, or is it necessary for u-boot?